# XRF analysis - recalculating results

Tags: geochemistry, petrology

For TAS diagram plot, one need to recalculate Major oxide data (NaO, K2O, SiO2).

Do one need to recalculate the ppms of Zr,Nb and Y and % of TiO2 for Zr/TiO2 vs Nb/Y diagram plotting for rock classification?

Comment: By recalculate, you mean on an anhydrous basis?

Comment: Yes anhydrous basis. Say you have %5 LOI then you recalculate 95% to 100%. by increasing all oxides about %5 times. Then the sum is %100 again.

Comment: Do you just mean renormalize so everything adds up to 100% after LOI?

Just divide through by the sum of everything after LOI and everything should add back up to 100%. But it should not have a huge effect on the TAS diagram.

Comment: g.z. i did normalisation for TAS. My question is different. I am asking if renormalizing is needed for other diagrams such as Zr/TiO2 - Nb/Y (winchester diagram) by normalising the values of TiO2,% and Zr, Nb, Y. ppm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to recalculate all major oxide (including TiO2), trace elements are not important. No need to recalculate them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the element ratios, you are looking at their relative abundance, not the absolute abundance. Therefore, as long as all the data you are comparing come from XRF, you do not need to normalise them for the ratio calculations in the plots.

Comment: Parent magma gathers secondary volatiles by hydrothermal and weathering alteration during post volcanic processes. When we analyse the relative abundance of the elements with the addition of the secondary volatiles we will get low values on analyses results than the original value of the elements. So relative abundance of the elements in the XRF are renormalized. Element values increasing by renormalization. Say if we have 5% volatile and 60% SiO2 in the analyses result, then ask if i have 60%SiO2 in 95% total what would i have for %100. The normalized result will be 63,16.

Comment: You are correct for the TAS plot (which uses absolute abundance), but if all the elements are increasing by 5 %, then their ratios will stay the same. e.g. (1.05*SiO2)/(1.05*K2O) = SiO2/K2O. So Normalization is not necessary for ratio plots. However indeed it is probably a good idea to normalize all the data for consistency.

Comment: We lncrease x and y values, with m coefficient so the position changes in  Cartesian plane. the x/y ratio doesn’t changing by increasing x and y with m. Xm/ Ym= X/Y . So the point in SiO2 to Na2O+K2O will be translated by  normalization on the plot. Zr/TiO2 value will not change  after normalization. It is better not to use The relative and absolute abundance terms, to keep it simple, Analysis results are already giving relative abundance of elements